# Implementing Stripe-like basic authentication

Tags: rest, api, stripe-payments, basic-authentication

I was looking around to find ideas to do REST API authentication method and stumbled upon Stripe's API. I looked that it only passes username for its basic authentication method.

I tried to implement it and stops because I am confused on how do they store the keys. Do they store the keys in clear text or do they store in being hashed? If it is being hashed, how do they compare the clear API key with the hashed API key in the database without other parameters being passed (e.g username, email, id etc.)?

Comment: Could you clarify which bit of Stripe's API you're referring to? If it's https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication, API keys aren't exactly the same as usernames.

Comment: Hey @ceejayoz, yes I was referring to the https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication. I mean I want to understand the flow. I was wondering if they are hashing the API key in their database or not.

Comment: They can't be storing them one-way hashed, as they're available to you in the Stripe dashboard on-demand. Hashes are irreversible; they wouldn't be able to let you view your API keys if they were.

Comment: Hmm. Let's say some malicious person have access to Stripe's database, he would be able to see the API keys in clear text and use it? @ceejayoz

Comment: They are likely stored encrypted, and carefully protected. Given Stripe's size and the fact that they store large numbers of credit cards, that they haven't had a breach is a pretty good sign they've got a good security model.

Comment: Let's see if I my logic is accurate. If someone registers, the backend generates an API token. Then store the API token to the database while also being encrypted with a symmetric encryption algorithm. For authenticating, the user pass the clear text API key, backend encrypt the clear text API token with encryption key, and try to find the encrypted API key in the database. @ceejayoz

Comment: If you want to know if that's *accurate*, you'll need to go work at Stripe. None of it's really relevant when working *with* Stripe's APIs.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the responses! @ceejayoz